# How to define the model for this situation?

Tags: django, django-models

I have defined a Build model as following:

- One Job can contain multiple Jenkins build.
- The `jenkins_build_id` field saves the related build `id` from jenkins.
- `Job_A` can contain `jenkins_build_id` like : 1 , 2 , 3
- `Job_B` can also contain `jenkins_build_id` like : 1 , 2 , 3

How can I define the model for a case where the `jenkins_build_id` in one Job is unique but can be the same with any other Job.

I found the similar example in the tutorial, but don't know how to modify it so that it can meet my needs.

`title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')`

```
class Build(models.Model):

    jenkins_build_id = models.PositiveIntegerField('Jenkins_Build_ID')

    job = models.ForeignKey(Job)
```

Comment: "The jenkins_build_id in one Job is unique but can be the same with the other Job?". So how exactly it is unique? Also fix your code and indentation; which class does the line starting with `title` belong to?

Answer (score 0):

I found can define the unique_together in Meta  ^^

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = ("jenkins_build_id", "job")
```